# Export tabulated string to an excel file

Tags: c#, excel

I have been scratching my head all day trying to get this to work, so if someone could help I would be very grateful.

I am able to export a tabulated string to an Excel file, when I open the file in Excel it looks fine (3 rows, 3 columns), however, the formatting must be dodgy as I can't read the same file using C#. If I do a save as from Excel, then I can now read it from my C# script.

```
fileWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Sheet1.xls");
fileWriter.Write("COL_A\tCOL_B\tCOL_C\r\n1\t2\t3\r\n10\t20\t30");
fileWriter.Close();
```

To read the Excel file back i'm using the following code:

```
OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + (@"C:\Sheet1.xls") + "; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;");

OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", cnn);
cnn.Open();
OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
DataTable forceResultsTable = new DataTable();
adp.Fill(forceResultsTable);
```

The error I'm getting back is "OleDbException was unhandled" with "cnn.Open();" highlighted

Comment: I'm not sure what is going on. I think we might need more information. However, have you tried opening the file using notepad or something similar to see what the formatting looks like outside of excel?

Comment: Just to note: When I do the saveas from Excel, the save as type defaults to "Text (Tab delimited) (*.txt)" which may be the issue for when I'm reading it back in C# ?

Comment: How are you reading it back? What sort of data do you get when it "isn't working"? Show some examples

Comment: Try using http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Comment: It'd be better if you can clarity what you mean by "the formatting is gogdy and you can't read it in C#".

Comment: sorry, I've just posted above how I'm reading the file back in